# good module is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I have registered good plugin in hapi server and all of my responses are getting logged in. But when I do a `console.log`, `console.error`, `console.warn`, `console.info` all the logs are getting printed in plain text but not in the good plugin way.

Can anyone help me with what I might have missed.

I have read following documentation:

- https://github.com/hapijs/good/blob/HEAD/API.md
- https://hapijs.com/tutorials/getting-started?lang=en_US

Answer (score 0):

console.log naturally goes to console. If you want to print things to console use something like:

`request.server.log(['error', 'contentFetch'], err);`

This is my good plugin configuration maybe you can ditch and find something works for you.

```
logging: {
        $filter: 'env',
        production: {
            reporters: {
                file: [{
                    module: 'good-squeeze',
                    name: 'Squeeze',
                    args: [{error: '*', log: ['error'], ops: '*'}]
                }, {
                    module: 'good-squeeze',
                    name: 'SafeJson',
                    args: [
                        null,
                        {separator: '\n'}
                    ]
                }, {
                    module: 'rotating-file-stream',
                    args: [
                        'error.log',
                        {
                            size: '10M', // rotate every 10 MegaBytes written
                            interval: '1d',  // rotate daily
                            compress: 'gzip', // compress rotated files
                            path: './logs'
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            }
        },
        $default: {
            ops: {
                interval: 1000
            },
            reporters: {
                console: [{
                    module: 'good-squeeze',
                    name: 'Squeeze',
                    args: [{log: '*', response: '*'}]
                }, {
                    module: 'good-console'
                }, 'stdout']
            }
        }
    },
```

Registering like this

```
{
        plugin: {
            register: 'good',
            options: Config.get('/logging')
        }
    }
```